# How I can see all documents per topic in LDA?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling

I am using LDA to know the themes of a great text. I managed to print the topics, but I would like to print each text with your topic.

**Data:**

```
it's very hot outside summer
there are not many flowers in winter
in the winter we eat hot food
in the summer we go to the sea
in winter we used many clothes
in summer we are on vacation
winter and summer are two seasons of the year
```

I tried to use sklearn and I can print the topics, but I would like to print all the phrases belonging to each topic

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
import numpy as np
import pandas

dataset = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
comments = dataset['comments']
comments_list = comments.values.tolist()

vect = CountVectorizer()
X = vect.fit_transform(comments_list)

lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_topics = 2, learning_method = "batch", max_iter = 25, random_state = 0)

document_topics = lda.fit_transform(X)

sorting = np.argsort(lda.components_, axis = 1)[:, ::-1]
feature_names = np.array(vect.get_feature_names())

docs = np.argsort(comments_list[:, 1])[::-1]
for i in docs[:4]:
    print(' '.join(i) + '\n')
```

**Good output:**

```
Topic 1
it's very hot outside summer
in the summer we go to the sea
in summer we are on vacation
winter and summer are two seasons of the year

Topic 2
there are not many flowers in winter
in the winter we eat hot food
in winter we used many clothes
winter and summer are two seasons of the year
```

Comment: You’ve got the docs and, for each doc, the document_topic. So simply iterate over your document_topics variable and store the topic and the indexes with a dictionary, for example.

Comment: Thanks @Norhther , so I should do: **for i in document_topics**?

Comment: document_topics has a topic for each of your documents. So you could do it with a for, storing the index. A dictionary of lists can do the work, where the list stores the indexes, and the keys are the topics.

Comment: Sorry, but if I understand correctly, I can not do it this way. I hope to have an output with a document **in the form of text** and its topic. If I do as you tell me, I will have a document **in number form** and its topic :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the documents, you need to specify them.

```
print(" ".join(comments_list[i].split(",")[:2]) + "\n")
```